# Do multiple declarations of the same Provider create new instances in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

**Question 1** In React 16.3.x will Providers share the same instance regardless of hierarchy?

**Question 2**  Will the LazyloadProvder with a shared `value` be the same instances?

```
const value1 = {wow: () => {}}
<App>
  <LazyloadProvider value={value1}>
    <LazyloadConsumer >
     <h1>hello sibling 1</h1>
    </LazyloadConsumer>
    <LazyloadProvider value={value1}>
      <LazyloadConsumer>
       <h1>hello sibling 1 - child nest</h1>
      </LazyloadConsumer>
    </LazyloadProvider>
  </LazyloadProvider>
  <LazyloadProvider value={value1}>
    <LazyloadConsumer>
     <h1>hello sibling 2</h1>
    </LazyloadConsumer>
  </LazyloadProvider>
</App>
```

**Question 3**  What about with different `values`?

```
const value1 = {wow: () => {}}
const value2 = {wow: () => {}}
const value3 = {wow: () => {}}
<App>
  <LazyloadProvider value={value1}>
    <LazyloadConsumer >
     <h1>hello sibling 1</h1>
    </LazyloadConsumer>
    <LazyloadProvider value={value2}>
      <LazyloadConsumer>
       <h1>hello sibling 1 - child nest</h1>
      </LazyloadConsumer>
    </LazyloadProvider>
  </LazyloadProvider>
  <LazyloadProvider value={value3}>
    <LazyloadConsumer>
     <h1>hello sibling 2</h1>
    </LazyloadConsumer>
  </LazyloadProvider>
</App>
```

I don't quite follow this github issue but I think it talking about something similar https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context `Consumer` receives a value from nearest `Provider`.

In case `<LazyloadConsumer>` is a child of `<LazyloadProvider value={value2}>`, `<LazyloadProvider value={value1}>` doesn't affect it.

It's the same logic as in variable scopes:

```
const foo = 1; // won't affect inner scope any way
{
  const foo = 2;
  console.log(foo); // 2
}
```

Comment: What about when they share the same value.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's same or different value. In case there's inner  `LazyloadProvider`, outer `LazyloadProvider` is ignored. It's also unclear what you meant by 'instance'.